# Jenkins on AWS elastic beanstalk: cannot touch '/var/jenkins_home/copy_reference_file.log': Permission denied

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to run a dockerised Jenkins and postgres database on AWS elastic beanstalk in a multi-container t2.micro environment:

Dockerrun.aws.json

```
{
"AWSEBDockerrunVersion": 2,
"containerDefinitions": [
    {
        "name": "postgres-db",
        "image": "postgres:9.5-alpine",
        "essential": true,
        "memory": 256,
        "portMappings": [
            {
                "hostPort": 5432,
                "containerPort": 5432
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "jenkins-blueocean",
        "image": "<account_id>.dkr.ecr.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/<image>:latest",
        "essential": true,
        "memory": 256,
        "mountPoints": [
            {
                "sourceVolume": "jenkins-data",
                "containerPath": "/var/jenkins_home"
            }
        ],
        "portMappings": [
            {
                "hostPort": 80,
                "containerPort": 8080
            }
        ],
        "links": [
            "postgres-db"
        ]
    }
],
"volumes": [
    {
        "name": "jenkins-data",
        "host": {
            "sourcePath": "/var/jenkins-data"
        }
    }
]
}
```

AWS shows it deploys fine but the logs for jenkins-blueocean container has that error:

> /var/log/containers/jenkins-blueocean-7ce78063214b-stdouterr.log
>
> touch: cannot touch '/var/jenkins_home/copy_reference_file.log': Permission denied
>
> Can not write to /var/jenkins_home/copy_reference_file.log. Wrong volume permissions?

Am I missing something to allow jenkins access to the volume?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure if this is the right path but we ended up following the `.ebextensions` method of running commands to setup the volume path to allow the `jenkins` user from the `jenkins-blueocean` container full access to do its thing.

```
mkdir -p /var/jenkins-data
chmod 777 /var/jenkins-data
```

This was because the permissions on the location in the docker instance has `r-x` rights for other users, with root user having `rwx`.